# How can I convert ip ranges formatted in ip1-ip2 to cidr format?

Tags: python, bash, format, ip, cidr

I have a long list of ips formatted like the following:

```
5.10.64.0-5.10.127.255
5.34.182.0-5.34.183.255
5.34.240.0-5.34.244.255
5.34.247.0-5.34.247.255
5.35.248.0-5.35.255.255
23.97.48.0-23.97.80.15
46.105.0.0-46.105.255.255
66.209.64.0-66.209.95.255
```

What I am trying to do is to get it into CIDR format, as such:

```
5.10.64.0-5.10.127.255 becomes:

5.10.64.0/24
5.10.65.0/24
...
5.10.127.0/24
```

Any advice on how to automate this process using a script is what I'm looking for.

Comment: Are you sure you are looking for 5.10.64.0/1 and not 5.10.64.0/24?

Comment: @Cyrus You are right, it is /24.

Comment: I suggest to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/q/25935602/3776858

Comment: @Cyrus thanks, the script pasted there does exactly what I need but I have over 2000 lines this has to be done for.

Comment: Do you need a script, or you need a ready tool/website where you can paste the ranges and get the cidr?

Comment: @Pikk either one is fine, I just need to be able to block all the ranges in htaccess.

Comment: @stevenchen was my answer what you were looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have the tool: http://ipconvertertools.com/iprange2cidr
For this tool 2000 IP ranges is not a problem.

You have to select the "multiple ip ranges" tab and paste all of them there. You can start with few ranges to test the tool.